# Google VR Reticle Click on UI Button

Tags: button, unity-game-engine, click, virtual-reality

So I am having this issue with using Google VR reticle where I cannot click a button. I have an image attached showing the heirarchy and the PlayButton is what I am trying to click. The Canvas has a Graphic Raycaster, the button has an Event Trigger that calls the method to navigate to the next scene. The UpScrollPanel, and DownScrollPanel work just fine. The EventSystem has the Gaze Input Module, as well as Event System, and Touch Input Module.

Any ideas on how to get this working? I have watched a few videos from NurFACEGAMES and while they helped a little, I haven't gotten the click to work yet.

Oh, and I am using Unity 5.3.4f

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes things can get in the way of the button, make sure that no other UI elements overlap it, for example text borders (which are actually larger than they appear). You can also fix this by moving the button up the hierarchy among its siblings, I believe the first child is top.

Also try moving the button up the hierarchy if possible, sometimes UI having certain parents makes them not work

The canvas object should have a graphic raycaster

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue to be unrelated to anything I thought it was. The menu I was using is a prefab I also use in another view that isn't VR. The scrollrect was loading that prefab, instead of the modified one I was using in the VR menu, and therefore the triggers I had added to the button were no being used when the app loaded.